# How to dynamically add button to jQuery-UI button-set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, button

I am looking for a way to add a button to a jQuery button-set at run-time with JavaScript.

```
        if(response.success) {
            var menuItem = document.createElement('a');

            $(menuItem).attr('href', response.href);
            $(menuItem).attr('category-id', response.id);
            $(menuItem).text(title);

            $("#menu-buttonset").append(menuItem);
        }
```

I am adding the hyperlink to the div container of the button-set using JavaScript, and then re-calling `buttonset()` on the container.

```
 $("#menu-buttonset").buttonset();
```

This however does not seem to rebuild the button-set as I expected.

I am not seeing any function in the jQuery API for this either.

Can anyone provide some insight?

**Resolved:**

Using refresh method as suggested, rebuilt the button-set.

```
$('#menu-buttonset').buttonset('refresh');
```

Comment: Is $(categoryItemSelector).parent() same as $("#menu-buttonset")?

Comment: Yes it is the same, the example has been updated to make this more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `refresh` method after adding an new item to the button set.

```
$("#menu-buttonset").append(menuItem).buttonset('refresh');
```

I cannot find any documentation for this method in jquery, but it is available.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how I missed that in the documentation.

Comment: [Button API Documentation - Refresh](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#method-refresh) is available now in documentation.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like buttonsets use radiobuttons or checkboxes, not links:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Button

Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fe9Tx/1/
(Fixed it so selection works)

Comment: After several minutes of searching - this was the exact answer I was looking for. zsalzbank - thanks for taking the time!!